# Bypass Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) in Angular $http.get service

Tags: angularjs, cors

I have an Angular Service that uses $http.get as below

```
var myService = angular.module('myService', []);
myService.factory('myFactory', ['$http',function($http) {
  return {
    getResponse: function(callback) {
      return $http.get("url")
        .success(callback)
        .error(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
  };
}]);
```

But I get

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://8000/. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin
```

Is there anything I can do to get the proper response and off this CORS issue.

Answer (score 1):

So, a quick way to bypass this CORS error is to get a JSONP style of response. Which calls the callback function with the response gotten. We could want to try attaching a JSON_CALLBACK as a query on the url, and change the $http.get method to $http.jsonp method. SO you would want to do something like;

```
var myService = angular.module('myService', []);
    myService.factory('myFactory', ['$http',function($http) {
      return {
        getResponse: function(callback) {
          return $http.jsonp("url&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
            .success(callback)
            .error(function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
      };
    }]);
```

I hope it works for anybody that needs it.